# I am not able to plot two columns from my data set

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am currently trying to plot data where the `x` variable is the year and the `y` variable is the number of wins the Philadelphia Phillies won in a season.  I have tried multiple methods of plotting these two variables from my data set however nothing is working.  Below is the last option that I tried.

The first column of my file is the year and the third column is the number of wins (aka columns 0 and 2).

I've tried setting x and y to the columns and what I have below is what I most recently tried.

```
import csv
import numpy
import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=(10,6)

phillies_data = 
pd.read_csv('/Users/hannahbeegle/Desktop/Teams/PHILLIEScsv.csv', 
header = None)

phillies_data.plot(x='Year',y='W')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Wins')
plt.title('Amount of Wins in Phillies History (1871-2018)')
plt.xlim(1870, 2020)
plt.ylim(0, 170)

plt.show()
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2657, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 129, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: 'Year'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hannahbeegle/Desktop/Text Files/TeamDataBase.py", line 121, in 
    phillies_data.plot(x="Year", y="W")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 2942, in **call**
    sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 1973, in plot_frame
    **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 1763, in _plot
    elif not isinstance(data[x], ABCSeries):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2927, in **getitem**
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2659, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 129, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: 'Year'

> > > 

Comment: There is a misunderstanding of the parameters. the `x` and `y` arguments take ***the names of the columns*** in your dataframe, not the columns themselves. `df.plot(x="column1", y="column3")`

Comment: try to use .iloc untead of .loc ?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I did what you said and got this error that I edited above

Comment: We have no clue on how the dataframe looks like. See [mcve], or [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest file:///Users/hannahbeegle/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202019-06-18%20at%2012.30.27%20PM.png

Comment: Mhh, does this mean you invite people to hack into your computer to be able to access its Desktop folder? I think the second link above makes it perfectly clear how an example needs to look like?!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example in your jupyter session:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 2), columns=['BB', 'CC']).cumsum()
df['AA'] = pd.Series(list(range(len(df))))
df.plot(x='AA', y='BB')
```

You'll see a plot of `BB` vs `AA` (that is a column that increases 1 step at a time, while not plotting other column.
I hope that this can translate easily to your example.
If you need to check your column names try:

```
df.columns
```